# Cambiar valores de un RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

cómo puedo cambiar todas las letras A por un 9 y todas las letras B por un 8 en un RDD con una función lambda.
He intentado esto pero no funciona:

```
rdd.map(lambda a: 9 if a == "A" else a == a)
rdd.map(lambda a: 8 if a == 'B' else a == a)
```

Mi rdd de ejemplo:

```
[[u'55', u'A', u'433235', u'12', u'09'], [u'2017', u'B', u'24212', u'4', u'1']]
```

Y tendría que pasar a:

```
[[u'55', u'9', u'433235', u'12', u'09'], [u'2017', u'8', u'24212', u'4', u'1']]
```

Gracias de antemano por vuestra generosa ayuda.

Comment: Creo que la forma correcta sería así: `lambda a: "9" if a == "A" else a`

Comment: Tampoco funciona. Alguna otra idea? Gracias Patricio

Comment: Sin conocer Spark, la función lambda única para hacer esto en Python sería `lambda a: u"9" if a == u"A" else u"8" if a == u"B" else a`. Ahora bien, al tratarse de elementos anidados si fuera una lista en Python podriamos hacer `lambda a: [u"9" if i == u"A" else u"8" if i == u"B" else i for i in a]`. Repito, esto sería en Python puro, no se como está implementado `map` en Spark

Comment: Te lo agradezco pero no me funciona ninguna de las dos maneras :(
Gracias por tu ayuda. Espero ayuda de más gente, gracias de antemano!

Comment: Supongo que debes saberlo pero `map` no cambia los valores dentro de un RDD, de hecho estos son inmutables. `map` retorna otro RDD nuevo con la función aplicada. Literal de la documentación: "Return a **new distributed dataset** formed by passing each element of the source through a function func. "

Answer (score 0):

Como dice @FJSevilla, map retorna un RDD nuevo, solo tienes que guardarlo.
Además, el else no es a==a porque eso siempre devolverá True, es simplemente a.

Sería algo así:

```
rdd_nuevo = rdd.map(lambda a: '9' if a == 'A' else a)
```